# Trouble with pricing table in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I've recently encountered a problem while making my website. I created a pricing table from a snippet I grabbed off of www.coveloping.com; I really like it, but once I input the HTML and CSS it automatically indents everything within my tables. Here is a screenshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/0962ewjwc7 - I know this might be pretty noobish, and there is probably a very easy solution, though I have searched through the source code using dev tools and still have not found the issue.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could get me through this; thanks in advance for your help!

```
<div class="pricing-table" id="pricing-table"> 
    <ul> 
        <li class="heading">Bronze</li> 
        <li class="price">£20</li> 
        <li>Starter package</li> 
        <li>15 Projects</li> 
        <li class="action">Buy Now</li> 
    </ul> 
    <ul> 
        <li class="heading">Silver</li> 
        <li class="price">£60</li> 
        <li>Intermediate package</li> 
        <li>20 Projects</li> 
        <li class="action">Buy Now</li> 
    </ul> 
    <ul> 
        <li class="heading">Gold</li> 
        <li class="price">£80</li> 
        <li>Professional package</li> 
        <li>30 Projects</li> 
        <li class="action">Buy Now</li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: I added the code to a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fyjYL/ and it displays just fine. I don't see that extra space.

Comment: Thanks for checking, it seems to work fine on other themes as well. Could it be something within my theme? I feel that it might be the case, though I'm not sure what it would be. =\

Comment: I've put this on hold because it isn't self-contained (lacks a [mcve]) and, in fact, the solution depended on modifying code that is not part of the question. So, this question is not likely to be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is causing that problem is this bit of code.

```
.entry-content li, .comment-content li, .mu_register li 
{
     margin: 0 0 0 36px;
     margin: 0 0 0 2.571428571rem;
}
```

It can be fixed by removing that bit of code or adding the following:

```
#pricing-table ul li 
{
    margin-left: 0px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much howlin, im not sure how I missed that! My attention to detail must be off. Nonetheless very much appreciate your time and help! :)